# Reduce function in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am new to the dc.js library and wanted to do the crossfilter calculation below on group method of my geochoropleth chart. I am pretty sure there is some function I could pass to the `reduce` method of `group`.

I have the following data in `DATA.csv` (the first row contains column names):

```
BUDGET,GID,MDIS,USPRO,TYPE,FILEURL,RVID,VERDATE,VERSTAT,SCORE
10428,ALI-G-006,Aliabad,Kunduz,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA North/136-SIKA-North-ALI-G-006.pdf,0,19-08-2014,2,0
24853,ALI-G-008,Aliabad,Kunduz,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA North/561-SIKA-North-ALI-G-008.pdf,0,19-08-2014,0
24831,ALI-G-019,Aliabad,Kunduz,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA North/987-SIKA-North-ALI-G-019.pdf,0,18-08-2014,2,0
24771,IMA-G-017,Imam Sahib,Kunduz,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA North/557-SIKA-North- IMA-G-017.pdf,0,28-08-2014,2,1
21818,IMA-G-019,Imam Sahib,Kunduz,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA North/992-SIKA-North-IMA-G-019.pdf,0,27-08-2014,2,0
12266,KHA-G-007,Khanabad,Kunduz,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA North/583-SIKA-North - KHA-G-007.pdf,0,7/9/2014,1,0
23148,KUN-G-002,Kunduz,Kunduz,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA North/909-SIKA-North - KUN-G-002.pdf,0,1/9/2014,2,0
54584,KUN-G-004,Kunduz,Kunduz,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA North/702-SIKA-North - KUN-G-004 20140709.pdf,0,9/7/2014,1,0
24544,PUL-G-001,Pul-e Khumri,Baghlan,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA North/599-SIKA-North - PUL-G-001 - 20140623.pdf,0,6/7/2014,2,1
40149,SSKDAG046,Arghandab (1),Kandahar,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA South/239-SIKA-South-SSKDAG046.pdf,0,12/9/2014,0,0.625
39452,0003 LGR MAG,Muhammad Aghah,Logar,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA East/792-SIKA-East - 0003 LGR MAG - 20140610.pdf,0,10/6/2014,2,0.7
58298,0013 LGR MAG,Muhammad Aghah,Logar,Hard,/uploadedfiles/reports/SIKA East/591-SIKA-East - 0013 LGR MAG 20140601.pdf,0,1/6/2014,2,0]
```

Below is the dimension and group for my chart:

```js
var facts = crossfilter(data);
var scoref = facts.dimension(function (d) { return d.district;});

var scoreg = scoref.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.score;});
```

The `d.score` field's value is calculated using the code below with PHP:

```php
$tempsql = $dbase->query('select "VERMDIS", COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, SUM("VERSTAT") AS SAM FROM mt_fver GROUP BY "VERMDIS"');

while ($r = pg_fetch_array($tempsql)) {
    $dist = $r['VERMDIS'];
    $score = $r[2] / (2 * $r[1]);   
    $disxx[$dist] = $score;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to do the same calculation using `group().reduce(function (p,v) { /* ... */ })` from the dc.js library while grouping the values by district names.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The [tag:dc] tag is for an entirely unrelated programming language, so I removed it. I also made other improvements to your question.

Answer (score 2):

What results/errors are you getting? Looks like pretty much the right idea, but take into account:

- if you're using `d3.csv()`, it will return the values as strings, so you'll need either to preprocess your data, or use `+d.score` to convert the values while reading them
- the field may come out as `d.SCORE` depending how you are reading the CSV in.
- you may need to adapt the reduce function to suit your calculation

If you put a line break in the function you pass to reduce, you can set a breakpoint there using the browser's debugger and experiment on the console to figure out what expression works for what you need.

Comment: Many Thanks for the response,

In fact my approach is working if i am not applying any filters(not clicking on any chart) i am using d3.csv() and the data that it returns is working, however i don't want the SCORE field to be calculated using php when I am generating the CSV file, in fact there should not be any SCORE field in my CSV, I would like to do the calculation using VERSTAT field when i am creating the group for my chart so it works also with filters, VERSTAT field has three values of (0,1,2) and i want below formula when grouping based on MDIS field ->   Sum(VERSTAT)/(2*count(MDIS))

Comment: Ah, I should have asked for clarification. I really don't know the exact formula you want but it looks like some form of average. If you take a look at the [annotated stock example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) there are some averages calculated there.